# Making a search engine of sorts and I'm stuck

Tags: c#, for-loop, search

I'm writing a code using C# for my school. I'm a noob when it comes to programming and this is my first course in programming.

I'm making a program with menuchoices where the goal is to be able to save a string title and body in two vektors. Then you will have the option to search for a title and if your search matches with a existing title the title and body will show up on the screen. Then you'll also be able too look upp all saved titles and bodys in another menuchoice.

I'm stuck on case 2: were I need to make a search engine to find a title in bloggInlägg[0] and when my search matches both bloggInlägg0 and bloggInlägg1 should show up in the program.

Everything is written in swedish but

- menuchoice 1: is to add a title and body,
- menuchoice 2 is to search for a title and then displaying both the title and body,
- menuchoice 3 is to display all of my already made titles and bodys and
- menuchoice 4 is to stop the program.

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool kör = true;
    List<string[]> bloggen = new List<string[]>();
    
    while (kör)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[1] Lägg till ett nytt inlägg i bloggen:");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] Sök inlägg i bloggen: ");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] Skriv ut alla blogginlägg: ");
        Console.WriteLine("[4] Avsluta programmet: ");

        string[] bloggInlägg = new string[2];
        int menyVal;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out menyVal);

        switch (menyVal)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Välj titel till inlägget: ");
                bloggInlägg[0] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Nu kan du skriva ditt inlägg: ");
                bloggInlägg[1] = Console.ReadLine();

                bloggen.Add(bloggInlägg);

                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Ange titel på inlägget du söker: ");
                string searchWord = Console.ReadLine();
                bool hittad = false;

                for (int i = 0; i < bloggInlägg.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (bloggInlägg[0] == searchWord) // om man ordet man söker efter matchar
                    {
                        hittad = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Din sökning hittades: " + bloggInlägg[0]);
                    }
                }

                if (hittad == false) // om man ordet man söker efter inte matchar
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Din sökning hittades inte");
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Här är en lista på alla blogginlägg du sparat: ");
                foreach (var item in bloggen)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item[0] + " " + item[1]);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("Hejdå");
                Console.ReadLine();
                kör = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < bloggInlägg.Length; i++)` you are traversing the wrong collection. You want to look in `bloggen[i][0]` for the title and on hit display that along with `bloggen[i][1]`.

Comment: And also: As-is you need to enter _exactly_ the title to find it. You may want to consider using `string.Substring` or [`string.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

The loop in case 2 is flawed.
I think you want to loop through all the items and, if the Title or Body contains the word, then print the Title.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bloggen.Count; i++)
{
    var currentBloggen = bloggen[i];
    if (currentBloggen[0].Contains(searchWord) || currentBloggen[1].Contains(searchWord))                    
    {
        hittad = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Din sökning hittades: " + currentBloggen[0]);
    }
}
```

It is worth a look at the foreach statement to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

This gives you slightly neater code:

```
foreach (var currentBloggen in bloggen)
{
    if (currentBloggen[0].Contains(searchWord) || currentBloggen[1].Contains(searchWord))                    
    {
        hittad = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Din sökning hittades: " + currentBloggen[0]);
    }
}
```

Then look at how to create a class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes.

You could create a class called Bloggen with 2 properties, for the Title and Body and use that object for your bloggInlägg,

```
class Bloggen
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

This will make the code a lot easier to read.

```
foreach (var currentBloggen in bloggen)
{
    if (currentBloggen.Title.Contains(searchWord) || currentBloggen.Body.Contains(searchWord))                    
    {
        hittad = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Din sökning hittades: " + currentBloggen.Title);
    }
}
```

Finally, create a method in the Bloggen class called "IsMatch"

```
class Bloggen
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public bool IsMatch(string word)
    {
        return Title.Contains(searchWord) || Body.Contains(searchWord);
    }
}
```

And the loop becomes:

```
foreach (var currentBloggen in bloggen)
{
    if (currentBloggen.IsMatch(searchWord))                    
    {
        hittad = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Din sökning hittades: " + currentBloggen.Title);
    }
}
```

--- other changes are required to implement the class but I will leave that for you to discover :)

Comment: Dude thank you and thanks for the fast answer aswell. You're abit above my skill level in this, we dont use currentBloggen and that yet but if you know how to do it without using current that would be nice but I can probably use it without it becoming a problem. Still thanks alot I appreciate you.